# What's the pressure on the convex surface of an air bubble just below the water surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension

In context to some other question about excess pressure inside an air bubble in water, my textbook has used the pressure on the convex surface of the air bubble "just below the water surface" to be equal to atmospheric pressure. Why is that so?